# XPath отлавливает другой элемент через contains()

Tags: python, xpath

Через `XPath` пытаюсь получить элемент, дата которого - 25.10, а `class` элемента с датой - `event__time`. Путь такой:

```
//div[@class='event__time' and contains(text(), 25.10)]
```

Почему-то находит элементы

```
<div class="event__time">25.11. 02:30</div>
<div class="event__time">25.11. 05:00</div>
<div class="event__time">25.11. 08:00</div>
```

Почему на них реагирует данный путь? Там ведь не такой месяц. Как это исправить?

Comment: В xpath 2+ показанный путь в принципе не работает, потому что второй аргумент contains должен быть строкой. И если сделать его строкой, то ничего не находит, как и должно

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, помогло